# getAccessoryList NOT returning null when USB Detached

Tags: android, usb

I have a method that gets a list of the USB accessories attached to the device and updates the List Collection `usbAccessories` which is used by an adapter to populate a `ListView`, i.e.,

```
private void updateUsbAccessories() {
    List<String> usbAccessories = new ArrayList<String>();

    UsbAccessory[] accessoryList = usbManager.getAccessoryList();

    if (accessoryList != null) {
        usbAccessories.add(accessoryList[0].getSerial());
    }

    // Notify adapter of changes
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

I call this method when the USB accessory is detached from the device using the `BroadcastReceiver`

```
class UsbReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateUsbAccessories();
    }
}
```

which listens for the intent filter with action `ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED`. The problem is that the behavior appears to be very intermittent, i.e., sometimes when I detach the device `accessoryList.length = 1`. Surely this should always return `null` since there isn't any USB accessories attached.

Any ideas why this might be happening? Thnx.

**Update**
I'm starting to wonder whether Android sends the `ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED` broadcast before the accessory has actually been detached, i.e., I introduced a small sleep in the `UsbReceiver` as follows:

```
class UsbReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            updateUsbAccessories();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {} 
    }
}
```

With this small sleep in place I can't seem to recreate the problem. Without it I can only presume that I call `getAccessoryList` in method `updateUsbAccessories` before the accessory has actually detached, despite the broadcast having been sent. Could this really be the problem? If so, I'm not sure about Android's implementation of when to send the `ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED` broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with you, that Android doesn't detect the ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED event...
and I found out what the problem is

The most likely problem is your USB host power ON/OFF to quickly before Android can send the ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED to your application

**Solution**
i) Change your USB host firmware to add a delay after the OFF before ON it again (maybe 200ms - works for me)
ii) Add a delay in the thread as you have suggested!